# length of dbName is max 10

Tags: fiware-orion

Why is there a such a short maximum length for the used database?

I'm considering a pull request to make it larger, but I would like to know the reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB limits DB name length to 64 characteres, as stated in [its documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Length-of-Database-Names):

> Database names cannot be empty and must have fewer than 64 characters.

When Orion runs in `-multiservice` mode, each service is associated to a database, which name is as follows:

```
<db_prefix>-<service_name>
```

where `<db_prefix>` is the value of the `-db` CLI parameter (`orion` by default) and `<service_name>` is the name of the service (i.e. the one that comes in the `Fiware-Service` header in requests).

On the other hand, service names are limited to 50 characters (as stated in [Orion documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/multitenancy/index.html)).

Thus, if `<db_prefix>` maximum length is 10 then the maximum length for a DB name will be: 10 (max db prefix) + 50 (max service name) + 1 (for the `-`) = 61, which is less than the maximum 64 allowed at DB level.

We could have chosen 12 as maximum db prefix (for a total maximum of 63 at DB level), but we liked 10 as round number :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. If you do not run in a multi-tenant setup however, you are still limited to the 10 chars?

Comment: Yes. Having a common maximum for cases allows to switch Orion without problems from multi-tentan to mono-tentant setup and the other way around.

Comment: I dont quit see how you can switch from a multi-tenant (with 1 tenant) to mono-tenant, if the db argument only allows 10 chars?

Comment: Same goes for the other way arround: when switching from mono to multi service. Your (mono-service) instance must contain a '-' somewhere before the 10th character, or you cannot reuse the database.

Comment: Being precise, what I mean is that the orion DB (or the one used for `-db`) could be used in a mono-tenant setup, then you could re-start Orion in multi-tenant and that DB still being reachable in the "default tenant" (the one which is associated to request without Fiware-Service header). The other way arround, you could have a multi-tenant setup with serveral DBs (orion, orion-servA, orion-servB, etc.) then re-start Orion in mono-tentant and having the "orion" DB valid (of course, orion-servA or orion-servB would be unreachable this case).

Comment: Thats only true if the the Orion DB has a name less than 10 characters. When switching from multi to mono, I agree!